# three level nested url in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my app.js

```
 .state('dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
           templateUrl : 'resources/components/dashboard/dashboard.html',
            controller : 'dashboardController',   


        }).state('dashboard.profile', {
            url: '/profile',
           templateUrl : 'resources/components/clinicprofile/profile.html',
            controller : 'profileController',


        }).state('dashboard.setting', {
            url: '/setting',
           templateUrl : 'resources/components/setting/settings.html',
            controller : 'profileController',

        }).state('dashboard.setting.user', {
            url: '/user',
           templateUrl : 'resources/components/setting/user.html',
            controller : 'profileController',
```

**Note that** my three level nested url is working fine when i am puttin ng-view in setting.html page
but i dont want to show the content of setting.html when a user is on

```
dashboard/setting/user
```

it is showing setting page content as well as user page content

i dont want to show the content of setting.html when a user is on user page

i want to show only user content on this url  `dashboard/setting/user` how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the user page to be included in the settings page, it cannot be a child of settings, so a possible solution would be using an abstract state and changing the settings URL to something like *setting/main*:

```
.state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'resources/components/dashboard/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'dashboardController',   

    }).state('dashboard.setting', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/setting',
        template: '<ui-view></ui-view>',

    }).state('dashboard.setting.main', {
        url: '/main',
        templateUrl: 'resources/components/setting/settings.html',
        controller: 'profileController',

    }).state('dashboard.setting.user', {
        url: '/user',
        templateUrl : 'resources/components/setting/user.html',
        controller : 'profileController',
    })
```

[UI Router documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views)